# Business Schengen Visa

Tags: visas, schengen, business-travel

I applied for a Schengen visa, and included a business invitation and a letter from the inviting company saying that they will be responsible for all expenses. I also submitted my bank statment as part of the documents requested. The bank statement was issued on 29th of the month, so it didn't have a lot of money in the account (nearly zero). However, it does show that my salary is transferred on monthly basis into the account (4600€ a month). Could you please advise if that might affect the approval?

Comment: See [this excellent answer](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/66104/should-i-submit-bank-statements-when-applying-for-a-uk-visa-what-do-they-say-ab) about bank statements in the context of UK visas -- it's not much different for Schengen. Basically they're not interested in the final balance as much as the history of the account.

Comment: For a business trip (where your expenses are presumably paid by your employer) the bank statement would be comparatively unimportant, since you don't need to document that you can personally afford the trip. I suppose they still like to see a monthly income that's larger than what you might expect to make as an undocumented immigrant, though.

Comment: Henning Makholm It is stated that i am receiving an amount of 4600 Euro / Month but as I stated the last amount was very less will it affect??

Comment: How long is your trip? Who is paying for travel and accommodation?

Comment: Burhan Khalid it is 6 Days and I Submitted a letter that the inviting company will be responsible for all expenses.

Comment: x @Ahmed: if it's clear from the statements you submitted that you have a _regular monthly income_ of 4600 euro, then I can't imagine you will have any problems on that front. (But really, what do you get out of hearing this kind of opinions from random people on the internet? You've already submitted your application; its outcome will be what it will be, and there's nothing you can actually _use_ unqualified guesses like mine for at the present time anyway).

Comment: Henning Makholm:) I completely agree with you it just jumped to my head now so I thought to ask just to know how things moving specially that it is my first visit to Germany and I don't want to lose it, anyway thanks for your answer, which I believe is quit reasonable

Comment: isn't this just yet another duplicate visa-bank-balance question???

Comment: @JoeBlow It's more of a duplicate "post-submission anxiety" question.

Answer (score 1):

No one can tell you what will or won't affect your approval of the visa application; it is at the sole discretion of the officer that reviews your application.

As you have already applied and frankly not much you can about it at this time, it is simply a matter of waiting for the result and then deciding what next steps to take.